# How Do I Get Customer Input To Display?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I am in an Object-Oriented Programming course in college and I have to use Java to start a program that will eventually incorporate a full on GUI by the end of the course.  For the beginning of this project, I have to basically use message boxes to set up how a customer would order a sub to be delivered to their home.

Here's what I have so far:

This is the main class

```
import javax.swing.*;

//Here is the main class

public class Subs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Begin Main Method
        char letter;
        String input;
        String input1, input2, input3, input4, input6, input8;
    int input5, input7;
        int subL; //length of sub in inches
        int cup; //size of drink in ounces

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Message");


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Welcome to Famous Subs! ");
        input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please Enter Your Name:       ");
        input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please Enter Your Address: ");
        do { 
            input3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What kind of sub would "
                + "you like? " +
                "\n Turkey Club" +
                "\n Philly" +
                "\n Meatball" +
                "\n Chicken Parm");

            input4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What type of bread? " +
                "\n White" +
                "\n Wheat" +
                "\n Rosemary" +
                "\n Italian Herb");
            subL = getValidLength();

            input6 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What would you like to "
                + "to drink? " +
                "\n Water" +
                "\n Soda" +
                "\n Juice");
            cup = getValidCup ();
            input8 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Do you wish to continue?\n "+
                                             "'y' or 'Y' for YES\n"+
                                             "'n' or 'N' for NO\n");
            Order firstOrder = new Order(input1, input2, input3, input4, input6, subL, cup);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, firstOrder.toString());
        letter = input1.charAt(0);
        }

        while (letter == 'Y'|| letter == 'y');

        System.exit(0);

    }

    private static int getValidLength()
{
    int s;
    String input5;
    do{
        input5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What size of sub do you wish "
                                              + "to order? "+
                                              "\n 6 inch"+
                                              "\n 12 inch");
        s = Integer.parseInt(input5);
    } while (!(s==6 || s==12));
    return s;
}

    private static int getValidCup()
    {
        int c;
        String input8;
        do{
            input8 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What size drink? " +
                "\n Small 12oz." +
                "\n Medium 24oz." +
                "\n Large 36oz.");

            c = Integer.parseInt(input8);
        }
        while (!(c==12 || c==24 || c==36));
        return c;
    }

}
```

This is my subclass

```
//This is the class for the order

public class Order {

    //creating my variables
    private String Customer;
    private String Address;
    private String name;
    private String bread;
    private String drink;
    private int length; //in inches
    private int size; //in ounces
    private double SubPrice;
    private double DrinkPrice;
    private double total;


    //blank constructor
    public Order(){}
    //Create a constructor to hold variables
    public Order (String Customer, String Address, String name, String bread, String drink, int subL, int cup){

        this.Customer = Customer;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.name = name;
        this.bread = bread;
        this.drink = drink;
        subL = length;
        cup = size;
    } 


    //create the getters and setters for the variables

    public String getCustomer(){
    return Customer;
}

public void setCustomer(String Customer){
    this.Customer = Customer;
}

public String getAddress(){
    return Address;
}

public void setAddress(String Address){
    this.Address = Address;
}
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBread(){
        return bread;
    }

    public void setBread(String bread){
        this.bread = bread;
    }

    public String getDrink(){
        return drink;
    }

    public void setDrink(String drink){
        this.drink = drink;
    }

    public int getLength(){
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength (int length){
        this.length = length;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize (int size){
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setSubPrice (int subL, double SubPrice){
        if (subL == 6)
            SubPrice = 7.95;
        else if (subL == 12)
            SubPrice = 12.75;
    }

    public void setDrinkPrice(int cup, double DrinkPrice){
        if (cup == 12)
            DrinkPrice = 2.00;
        else if (cup == 24)
            DrinkPrice = 4.00;
        else if (cup == 36);
            DrinkPrice = 6.00;
    }

    public void setTotal(){
        total = SubPrice + DrinkPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String grandOrder = "Greetings " + Customer +
            "\nHere is your order: " +
            "\n" + name +
            "\n" + bread +
            "\n" + drink +
            "\nThe length of your sub is: " + length +
            "\nThe size of your drink is: " + size +
            "\nThe Price for your sub is: " + SubPrice +
            "\nThe Price for your drink is: " + DrinkPrice +
            "\nHere is your total: $" + calculateTotal(DrinkPrice, SubPrice) +
            "\nThis will be delivered to: " + Address;
        return grandOrder;
    }
}
```

Everything runs just fine except the fact that the last box to show up returns all the string fields as null and the int and double variables as 0 or 0.0.

[image]

How do I return the values for what the user inputs on each dialog box? In addition, how do I get he customer's name and address to appear on this final screen?  Thanks.

Comment: 1. you aren't using your constructor 2. you need separate variables for each items because you are using the same var to get input String input. Which is getting overwritten every time you make the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize fields of your Order. You call constructor without parameters  public Order(){}. So you see the default values of the fields.

What you should do:

1. Be sure that you keep in a variable the value for the name of the client. (input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please Enter Your Name:       ");)
2. Be sure that you keep in variable user's input after  "input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What kind of sub would "
               + "you like? " ...".
3. After get all inputs from the user, create Order object passing user's values
   Order  firstOrder = new Order(name, bread,drink,int subL, cup);
4. Change the constructor with parameters like that:
   public Order (String name, String bread, String drink, int subL, int cup). You should not pass subPrice and drinkPrice because you Order class already know these values (see setdrinkPrice()). You determine the price of a cup based on the int cup. BTW, can you change the name of the method? Something like setDrinkPrice().
5. You never call setDrinkPrice() and setsubPrice()(should be setSubPrice(). You can do this when you calculate the total.

Start with these changes and if you have more problems ask .

Comment: So the constructor that has the variables within it is the problem?

Comment: Not setting the name on your firstOrder object means the getName will return a null String. Either firstOrder.setName(...) or using the new Order(firstName, ...)

Comment: No. The problem is that you never use it. In your main() you get user input but it looks that you never pass these values to your Order class. So, once you get values from the user do something like that: Order firstOrder = new Order("Sam", bread....,)

Comment: @Svetlana

So that means I have to pass some sort of arguments in that constructor within the main class?

Comment: Exactly. See my edited answer. I have some other advises for you.

Comment: @Svetlana I'm updating my post now with what I have to see if I am on the right track.

Comment: @Svetlana I think my code is up to date but I'm still having problems trying to get the drink size and the length showing up as well as the prices.  Any tips on that?

Comment: Your prices are calculated in setDrinkPrice() and setSubPrice() methods but you never call this methods therefore your prices have never been calculated. Once you create you object call these methods like: firstOrder.setDrinkPrice() and firstOrder.setSubPrices().  These methods should not accept any parameters because in your constructor you have already set the cup and subL.

Comment: Also check your constructor again. In you constructor there is variable Customer, but when you call this constructor you provide first the name .

Comment: You declare you constructor like that:public Order (String Customer, String Address, String name, String bread, String drink, int subL, int cup), but call it as new Order(name, Address,  sub, bread,  drink, subL, cup);  You do not provide to your constructor parameters in right order and type.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a few things are going on here.

```
Order firstOrder;
firstOrder = new Order();
```

Can just be written as

```
Order firstOrder = new Order();
```

there's no need to do that on two lines. But, more importantly, you've not giving it any parameters, so Java is linking that to the empty constructor (the one that doesn't assign anything.) All of that nice constructor code you have isn't getting called.

To do that, you need to actually do something with those `input` fields you keep assigning (at the moment you're just ignoring them and writing over them); specifically, you should store them in local variables, and then pass them to the constructor like:

```
 firstOrder = new Order(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Also, `Order` isn't a subclass; it isn't extending anything. (Except `Object`, but we don't generally call something a subclass just for that.

Comment: Alright so I fixed those input fields so now I need to do something with the constructor.  So that means I need to go into my Order class and pass like sample values to it so that the program knows what I'm trying to do correct?

Comment: Er... no, you need to pass the actual values you get from the input into the constructor. So long as you call new `Order()`, it's going to run the constructor whose header is `Order()` - the 0-arg constructor. Also, how did you fix the input fields?

Comment: Alright, so to pass those values, that goes in the main class right?  Also, I changed each area where 'input' shows up to something like 'input1, input2,' etc.

Comment: Yes, passing is done in the constructor call - where you have the  `new` keyword.

Comment: Alright progress.  Now within that constructor call, is that where those input fields go or sample information?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Sample Information". You would only give it sample values if you want to build an order that reflects specifically those values.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what goes in the constructor field in the class. I'm trying to pass the information but I think it is the inputs that need to go there.  It's been awhile since I've used java so I feel a bit more confused than normal.

Comment: So, the constructor describes how to build an instance of an object, given certain values. `public Order(){}` describes how to build an instance given NO values, so when you were passing it no values, it called that one. Instead you want to call ` public Order (String name, String bread, String drink, int subL, int cup, double subPrice, double drinkPrice)`, where `bread` is the type of bread, `drink` is the type of drink, etc; you got those values from the user and stored them in `input1`, etc, so that's what you should pass as your constructor arguments.

Comment: I just updated the code based on my interpretation of the collective feedback of the community that has responded. Care to take a look and see if I'm on the right track?

Comment: You're still calling the zero-arg constructor, it looks like. So, that class has no way of learning what its values should be, and will continue to keep the defaults (nulls and zeros)

Comment: Alright I got the nulls to actually change to the user input so that is a big time step forward.  Now it's just a matter of trying to figure out how to get those zeros to change to their respective numeric values

Answer (score 0):

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please Enter Your Name:       ");
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please Enter Your Address: ");
```

On the first line above, you get the customer's name. then you call the second line, throwing away the customer's name without saving it anywhere.